# query that selects pairs of sids that supply exactly the same part:

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following relations in MySQL:

```
Suppliers(**sid**; sname; city),
Parts(**pid**; pname; color),
Catalog(**sid**; **pid**; cost),
```

The keys are inbetween *.

I want to find:

1. The pairs of suppliers (s1; s2) such that s1 and s2 supply exactly the same parts.
2. The suppliers that supply at least two parts that are not supplied by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

1.The pairs of suppliers (s1; s2) such that s1 and s2 supply exactly the same parts :

```
select c1.sid,c2.sid
from catalog c1 join catalog c2 on c1.pid = c2.pid and c1.sid < c2.sid 
          and not exists 
          (
             select 1 
             from catalog c3 join catalog c4 
             on c3.sid = c1.id and c4.id = c2.sid 
                               and c3.pid <> c4.pid
          )
```

2.The suppliers that supply at least two parts that are not supplied by anyone else.

```
select c1.sid
from catalog c1 join catalog c2 on c1.sid = c2.sid and c1.pid < c2.pid 
          and not exists 
          (
             select 1 
             from catalog  
             where sid <> c1.sid and (pid = c1.pid or pid = c2.pid)
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT supplier_1, supplier_2
FROM (  SELECT c.sid AS supplier_1, c2.sid AS supplier 2, COUNT(*) AS total, COUNT(c2.sid) AS connected
        FROM Catalog AS c
        LEFT JOIN Catalog AS c2
        ON c.sid != c2.sid AND c.pid = c2.pid
        GROUP BY c.sid, c2.sid) AS h
GROUP BY LEAST(supplier_1, supplier_2), GREATEST(supplier_1, supplier_2)
```

I'd imagine something like this would do the trick. Basicly just do a `LEFT JOIN` based on not being equal to the same supplier and equal part id, then see if the amount of joins are equal to the amount of rows counted without successful joins.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your responses. I my self wrote the following queries but I am not sure if it is correct. please let me know. Thanks.

1)

SELECT T1.sid, T2.sid

FROM  T1,T2

WHERE (SELECT   T1.sid, C2.pid

```
   FROM( SELECT c1.pid

       FROM Catalog C1

       GROUP BY c1.sid) AS T1, Catalog C2

  WHERE T1.sid=c2.sid)
```

=

```
(SELECT   T2.sid, C4.pid

   FROM( SELECT c3.pid

       FROM Catalog C3

       GROUP BY c3.sid) AS T2, Catalog C4

  WHERE T2.sid=c4.sid)
```

2)

SELECT T1.S

FROM T1

WHERE NOT EXISTS(( SELECT c1.sid AS S, c1.pid AS p1, C2.pid AS p2

```
           FROM catalog AS C1, Catalog as C2

            WHERE c1.sid=c2.sid AND

            C1.pid<>c2.pid) AS T1

        EXCEPT

        ( SELECT c3.sid AS S1, c3.pid AS p3, C4.pid AS p4

           FROM catalog AS C3, Catalog as C4

           WHERE c3.sid=c4.sid AND

            c3.pid<>c4.pid) AS T2)
```

AND  NOT EXISTS((SELECT c3.sid AS S1, c3.pid AS p3, C4.pid AS p4

```
           FROM catalog AS C3, Catalog as C4

           WHERE c3.sid=c4.sid AND

            c3.pid<>c4.pid) AS T2)

        EXCEPT

        (SELECT c1.sid AS S, c1.pid AS p1, C2.pid AS p2

           FROM catalog AS C1, Catalog as C2

            WHERE c1.sid=c2.sid AND

            C1.pid<>c2.pid) AS T1
```